# Data Cleaning on 1 Million Rows of Data - .Net

Tags: .net, database, excel, datatable

I'm building a simple system to clean up some raw trading data using a self-built dictionary that scans the keywords in some columns and categorizes the rows.

The problem is that the program runs slow. On a 1-million-row dataset, it takes about 60 minutes to run through.

Is there a way to make it run faster? Here is the framework of my program (written in .Net):

*** Read the source file (Excel .xlsx) using OleDB connection, and populate it into a datatable using DataAdapter

```
Function ReadExcelToDatatable(filepath As String, sourceTblName As String, dataTblName As String) As DataTable
    ReadExcelToDatatable = New DataTable(dataTblName)
    Dim ext As String
    If Right(filepath, 4) = "xlsx" Then ext = "Xml" Else If Right(filepath, 4) = "xlsm" Then ext = "Macro" Else ext = ""
    Try
        Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & filepath & ";Extended Properties = ""Excel 12.0 " & ext & "; HDR=YES; IMEX=1""")
        Dim adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" & sourceTblName & "]", conn)
        adapter.Fill(ReadExcelToDatatable)
        adapter.Dispose()
        conn.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex)
        Console.WriteLine("Cannot read " & dataTblName & " to data table.")
    End Try
End Function
```

*** For each dictionary item, filter the datatable using DataTable.Select(Filter, Sort) and make changes

```
Sub DoFilterTables(rawTable As DataTable, dictTable As DataTable)
    For Each dictRow As DataRow In dictTable.Rows
        Try
            Dim rows As DataRow() = rawTable.Select(dictRow("IF COLUMN NAME 1") & " LIKE '%" & dictRow("KEYWORD 1") & "%'")
            For Each selectedRow As DataRow In rows
                If IsDBNull(selectedRow(CStr(dictRow("THEN COLUMN NAME")))) Then selectedRow(CStr(dictRow("THEN COLUMN NAME"))) = 1 Else selectedRow(CStr(dictRow("THEN COLUMN NAME"))) = dictRow("ASSIGNS KEYWORD 3") + selectedRow(CStr(dictRow("THEN COLUMN NAME")))
                selectedRow.AcceptChanges()
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex)
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to filter")
        End Try
    Next
End Sub
```

*** Save it as a text file row by row

```
Sub DataTable2CSV(ByVal table As DataTable, ByVal filename As String, _
ByVal sepChar As String)
    Dim writer As System.IO.StreamWriter
    Try
        writer = New System.IO.StreamWriter(filename)
        Dim str As String = ""
        Dim builder As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        For Each col As DataColumn In table.Columns
            str = str & col.ColumnName & sepChar
        Next
        str = str & vbCrLf
        writer.Write(str)
        Dim str2 As String = ""
        Dim ct As Long = 0
        For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
            str2 = ""
            For Each col As DataColumn In table.Columns
                Try
                    str2 = str2 & CStr(row(col.ColumnName)) & sepChar
                Catch ex As Exception
                    str2 = str2 & sepChar
                End Try
            Next
            str2 = str2 & vbCrLf
            writer.Write(str2)
        Next
    Finally
    End Try
    writer.Flush()
    writer.Close()
End Sub
```

End Module

Any input would be appreciated. Thanks!

---

EDIT

Turns out that 95% of the time are spent on reading Excel sheet into datatable using OleDB and DataAdapter..

Is OleDB -> DataAdapter the most efficient way of doing that?

Will CSV -> DataTable be a faster way?

What about Interops, in terms of performance?

Comment: code would be helpful

Comment: Can you also describe at a high level the rules you are using to clean up the data. 1. You should put in some basic profiling code (or use a tool) tomeasure how much time is spent doing what:loading data versus processing versus writing to file. This will let you know where to focus your efforts. 2. Do you have to use data tables? why not just iterate through the lines in your file, process a line, and output. 3. in the output routine, you have a stringbuilder declared, but you are not using it. the StringBuilder is MUCH more efficient at making strings than concatenation.

Comment: Jeremy, thanks for the input.

Definitely gonna use StringBuilder than concatenation, and will test out where the time is spent. On data cleaning, the reason I'm using datatable is that I figured using dataadapter to read/populate the data will be faster than my code reading each row, but I will test it out. The reason I'm iterating through rules, not through the rows, is that I expect only about 1/3 of them actually trigger the rule, so I figure maybe letting the Datatable.Select() do the work might be faster, no?

Comment: Yes I would imagine the Select will be quicker. Also putting a transaction around the writes to the database will speed that up too. You want to put a transaction around every 1000 or so writes not the whole 1M. After a certain number it won't speed it up much further. A 1M row transaction may cause memory problems.

Comment: When adding large amounts of data to an indexed table it can be quicker to drop the index(es) and then insert the data and recreate/add the index(es). Particularly on a empty table.

Comment: make sure the source table has index(es) defined so make your select work quickly without full table scans.

Comment: Since you reported that most of the time is loading the file, I would just save the Excel file as CSV, read one line, run logic to search and replace what needs to be changed, then immediately output that line to a new file. part of the problem with the datatable is that you are loading all million rows into RAM memory. If you process line by line, you are only storing that line before pushing it back out onto disk.

Comment: Excel is right at its limit of row at 1M rows. See https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-16c69c74-3d6a-4aaf-ba35-e6eb276e8eaa data  of this size is what a database was designed for. Excel won't work passed 1,048,576 rows.

Comment: Anthony, my thought was that it is a one time job, so that if Excel can handle it, it's fine to use it, no? Would using a database make reading data faster to OleDB to Excel file? I'm relatively new on this field.

Comment: Jeremy, thank you for the advice, will definitely try breaking down the line. My question is, as you would switch between reading and writing much more often,would it actually slow down the process?

Comment: Loading your datatable from CSV file would be more than 100 times faster than loading from excel file. So if you have the option, use CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to have a 5GB csv file hanging out on my computer with over 4 million lines in it, so I wrote a routine to just read in and out the first million with no processing. On my computer, this takes under 7 seconds.

In order to process the file line by line, you can use a snippet similar to the following:

```
        Dim counter As Integer
        Dim lStart, lEnd As Long
        lStart = Environment.TickCount
        Using r = System.IO.File.AppendText("C:\...\test.csv")
            For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadLines("C:\...\source.csv")


                r.WriteLine(line)

                counter += 1
                If counter = 1000000 Then
                    Exit For

                End If
            Next
        End Using
        lEnd = Environment.TickCount
        MsgBox("done: " & (lEnd - lStart))
```